# Как скрывать datepicker после выбора даты?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Использую календарь datepicker [Air Datepicker](http://t1m0n.name/air-datepicker/docs/index-ru.html) возникла потребность после выбора нужной даты скрыть календарь, в опциях такого не нашел, может нужно дописывать свои функции, не знаю. В любом случае помогите разобраться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то вот так.

```
$(function() {
  $('.datepicker').mousedown(function() {
    $('.datepicker--cell').click(function() {
      $(this).parents('.datepicker').removeClass('active');
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Там есть такая настройка как autoClose.

Comment: Благодарю, проглядел(